# Importing text files lines to certain text and combo boxes

Tags: c#, import, combobox, textbox, text-files

My apologies upfront if this is posted incorrectly. I will promptly take it down if requested.

I am (very much) a beginner of C# and Visual Studio. I have created a little program that exports data into a text file. See this picture: [image: http://imgur.com/a/0nCfr]

You'll see my program, the export feature, and the exported text file.

Now I want to do the reverse and *import* these created text files into my program.

My first guess is to somehow call the lines (or strings). But how would I get just pieces of the line into my text fields or combo boxes? For instance, see POINT 1 in the text file and the program.

I am not posting any code because I have not written any yet as I do not know where to start. Yet, I can post any of my existing code if requested.

I will do whatever I need to make it easier for you to help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so great with comboboxes as I haven't done any winforms stuff in a while, but here's how to get your text file data into your c# program:

`string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(yourPathToFileHere);`

This will insert each line of your text file as a string in an array (e.g. line 1 of your textfile = `fileEntries[0]`. Then you're probably going to want to split the line into individual items of interest so you'll want to use this:

`string[] partsOfString = yourString.Split('charToSplitOn');`

See if you can solve it yourself from there. If you still need help let me know and we'll go further! : )

EDIT1: A demo of `.Split()` in action!

```
string inputString = "POINT 1 123-123-123N 123-123-123W";

string[] results = inputString.Split('-', ' '); //split the input on hyphens and spaces
```

your results view will look like this:

```
results[0] = "POINT"
results[1] = "1"
results[2] = "123"
results[3] = "123"
results[4] = "123N"
results[5] = "123"
results[6] = "123"
results[7] = "123W"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I think I understand...

Would I put this string command under each text box and combobox accordingly?

Let's say I split the line. Is that done in character count? For instance, for POINT 1, I want to import "123" into the appropriate combobox. Would I specify, say, Line 10 and characters 10-12? However, this character count varies and this raises the question, what happens if I have only two characters? i.e. "12" instead of "123". 

I hope all that makes sense.

Comment: Okay so I ought to ask, why are you using a combo box and not a textbox?  To be clear a comboBox should be used when you have a 1-10 options or so for the user to select from. It's conventionally read-only. So if you want the user to also be able to input you should be using a textbox. And you're on the wrong track for what `.Split()` does. You're thinking of something entirely different. I'm going to edit my answer and include a example to demonstrate how to use it.

Comment: Also to answer your question: " Would I put this string command under each text box and combobox accordingly?", NO. It's best practice to load data in from a file once usually at the beginning of your program. So maybe consider making a button called `load-data-from-file` and that will build the array of strings. Then I'd use a `foreach` loop to do something with each line of data from your file.

Comment: I need users to set a value between 0-1000. The combobox I am using also supports text entry. I just thought it would be nice to have two options for the user to input the data, i.e. drop-down and manual entry. Also, it was the first way I learned how to do that lol. The demo you provided, will this only work if the text file includes, "POINT 1 123-123-123N 123-123-123W"? There are many text files with an infinite amount of POINT combinations. For example, "POINT 1 175-166-245N 142-167-456W". I can't stress enough that I am a beginner and still trying to grasp C# logic.

Comment: Sorry, I'm doing my best here to keep it high level for you. The demo I provided will work for all lines in your text files. Try it out and debug it a bit! Those numbers don't matter. They will still be split because they contain hyphens and spaces. It would work even if you gave it "POINT 9123 1c4-4ff-sssN cat-dog-000W".

Answer (score 0):

My first question is why you are using a combobox for a number that can supposedly go up to 123?  Are there limited options for your values because if not, I would instead use textboxes.

I would start by create a Object class for "Point" accepting 6 parameters for each of the values.  Then importing your text file data into your application with some sort of StreamReader or OpenFileDialog.  This is some **sample** code that you can use/change to fit your needs (working with beginning values and Point at the beginning of your line won't work for this code).

```
 Stream myStream;
 openFileDialog1.FileName = string.Empty;
 openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
   if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
     if (extension.Equals(".TXT", compareType))
     {
        try
        {
          using (myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile())
          {        
           string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName);

     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
     string line;
     while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
          string[] value = line.Split('-'); //Split line based on delimiter
          _pointList.Add(new Parameter(value[0], value[1], value[2], value[3], value[4], value[5]));
       }
```

If you want to populate your textbox, you can call each element from your list.

```
textbox1.Text = _pointList.ElementAt(0).Value1;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am still quite the newbie at all this. I am using combobox because, well, that was the first way I learned to have a list of text to choose from. I need the user to choose a value between 0-1000. The combobox worked so I used it lol. I don't yet understand how to proceed with your suggestion but I believe it stresses the need for me to buckle down on learning object-oriented programming.

Comment: @PortableAnswers Well, the sample code can be kind of confusing if you've never worked with a StreamReader or OpenFileDialog before - I had worked with something similar and that's what I provided you.  I wouldn't suggest using a combobox for 0-1000, instead I'd use a textbox because it is easier to set the value of a textbox than combobox and that's quite a few numbers to have the user select from.